# Kubernetes - read arguments "args" properties from .INI file or configMap

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes file with arguments that I am propagating through the `args`. Everything works OK!
Instead of the `args` can I read the configuration from some `.ini` or properties file or configMap ? I cannot find example for using the values from properties file or configMap instead of the `args` properties.
Or what will be the proposed best approach how these values should be read and how I should modify my `deployment YAML`.
Thanks!

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ads
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ads
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ads
        image: repo/ads:test1
        #args:
        args: ["-web_server", "10.1.1.1",
               "-web_name", "WEB_Test1",
               "-server_name", "ads"]
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ads
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, here's the official K8s [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) how to store properties in ConfigMap and how to access them in your container. If this document doesn't meet your requirement, do update your question with the reason and your exact expectation.

Comment: thanks. I will mark this as answer! Can you tell me what is the best way how I should read the `db_password` value? Is the best approach using the secrets or there is some other way? Thanks!

Comment: For credential data you should use [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/) instead of ConfigMap.